# Several websites unreachable on university network (w/o VPN)

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

So I don't know how to properly explain this issue of mine that I'm experiencing, and that is as follows: In my university network, I cannot connect to select websites (even websites of my own university) through WLAN. However, when I use the VPN provided by the university, I gain access to all websites (using Cisco AnyConnect). Normally, this shouldn't be the case; even without VPN, I am supposed to have access to any website (as is the case with my peers), funnier is, I never had any issues up until yesterday when this issue appeared out of the blue.

At home, everything works as usual, VPN or not. So I am at a total loss for what the issue could be.

Sorry for the fact that I haven't provided any technical info like logs or something. I'm not that well-versed in ubuntu but I did try several solutions posted elsewhere and nothing worked. If there's anything I can do to make the problem less vague, please let me know. What I do know is that I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you so much for your time, and have a nice day :)

---

Edit: Here's the ouput in terminal after running tracerote reddit.com:

```
traceroute to reddit.com (151.101.193.140), 64 hops max
  1  traceroute: sendto: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar
```

Furhtermore, it seems that several people are affected by this issue as well. I'm starting to get the feeling that the issue lies in the university network and not with my pc.

---

Edit 2:

- Output of ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:16:45:fa:96:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:ba:f8:84:4b:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2001:7c0:2049:1d5:d890:f5f7:46ea:a79b/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 43200sec
    inet6 2001:7c0:2049:1d5:ca55:b9ea:cb48:d54/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 43200sec
    inet6 fe80::db88:ba68:20e6:f9bf/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3a:db:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3a:db:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

- Output of ip r:

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Comment: Try rebooting your system, then see if you still have the problem.

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Open a terminal. Try `traceroute <website_or_IP_addr>` to a location you cannot reach.  Please edit your question to include the complete output.

Comment: Can you include the output of `ip a` and `ip r` in your question?